# Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided Uber Authentication in python

Tags: python, oauth, uber-api

I am working on integrating Uber Server-side API using python. I am able to run the authorization flow successfully and get the Access Token.

With the received Access Token I am able to get information like user profile, user history. But whenever I do a ride request ( using Sandbox ), the following error occurs.

```
HTTP/1.1 **401 Unauthorized**<br/>
Server: nginx<br/>
Date: Tue, 03 May 2016 09:29:19 GMT<br/>
Content-Type: application/json<br/>
Content-Length: 75<br/>
Connection: keep-alive<br/>
X-Uber-App: uberex-sandbox<br/>
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0<br/>
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff<br/>
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

{"message":"Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided.","code":"unauthorized"}.
```

I am not able to find the what exactly I missing with. 
Can anyone suggest what might be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authorization error "unauthorized" in this case indicates that the access token you are using is not sufficient for the endpoint you are trying to call. Because you describe that the access token was valid for other endpoints such as `GET /v1/me` but is not for `POST /v1/requests` I would speculate that the access token was not authorized for the `request` scope.

You can check this in two ways:

- In the [token exchange response](https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication#section-step-three-get-an-access-token), the scopes that have been granted are listed.
- If you are using v2 of Uber's OAuth, your access token is most likely a signed JWT. Use the debugger on [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/) to see the scopes that your access token has been authorized for.

If the access token is in-fact missing the `request` scope, you just need to explicitly specify that scope when sending the user to the authorization url.

E.g. `https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id=123&scopes=profile%20request...`

Keep in mind that the `request` scope is a limited access scope, meaning you can authorize the owner and any of the registered developers of your OAuth app for it while in development. When ready for production, submit a request to Uber for approval with a demo of your completed app.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. It used to work perfectly but now it stopped working. I had only the request scope working in both sandbox and prod url but now it just returns 401 on request/estimate. Have you made a change recently?

Comment: I have noticed that on the Oauth process, UBER adds 'offline_access' to the scope. What does that mean?

Comment: Ok I found the problem. It turns out the access token is now more than 255 char. So I had to upgrade the length a the access token field and it works fine now.

Comment: @Mehdi how did you do it?

Comment: @WilliaanLopes I just added more characters to my database column that stores the token. But Currently Uber has removed access to every one and is redistributing access rights to few selected companies